# GQL Not Recognising a ReferenceProperty in Filter

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I have a datastore thats has ~850 groups and ~19,000 items. Each item may belong to only one group, I have two models in my app that represent a Group and an Item:

```
class Group(db.Model):
    Id = db.IntegerProperty()
    Name = db.StringProperty()
    # ... some other  properties

class Item(db.Model):
    Id = db.IntegerProperty()
    Name = db.StringProperty()
    Group = db.ReferenceProperty(Group, collection_name="groupItems")
    # ... some other properties
```

I can use the datastore admin to view a specific item (i.e. WHERE Id = 34) and see that it is connected correctly to a Group -

```
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE Id = 34
```

This gives me a group with the following properties:

```
Decoded entity key: Group: id=10321
Entity key: agtzfmV2ZS1taW5lcnIMCxIFR3JvdXAY0VAM
Id: 18
```

If I alter my GQL query to retrieve all items for this Group I get no results! -

```
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE Group = KEY('agtzfmV2ZS1taW5lcnIMCxIFR3JvdXAY0VAM') -- No Results
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE Group = KEY('Group', 'agtzfmV2ZS1taW5lcnIMCxIFR3JvdXAY0VAM') -- No Results
```

If I retrieve just the group, it works as expected -

```
SELECT * FROM Group WHERE __key__ = KEY('agtzfmV2ZS1taW5lcnIMCxIFR3JvdXAY0VAM')  -- Returns 1 Group
```

This equally applies in my Python code. Calling:

```
group = Group.gql("WHERE Id = :1", 18).get()
items = Item.gql("WHERE Group = :1", group).fetch(50)
```

results in a list containing no items. Similarly

```
group.groupItems.fetch(500) -- Returns no results
```

My question is - am I doing something particularly stupid? I have created a dummy project with a similar structure to prove to myself that it wasnt a naming problem (i.e. that Group wasn't a reserved word) and that returns just fine. (Attached if anyone is interested).

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 1 :**

As requested, here's the creation code. Reader is a csv reader (using the inbuilt csv library) which opens a CSV stored in the BLOB store. For all intents and purposes its merely parsing a CSV file. As mentioned above. In the data viewer through my dashboard my Item is bound correctly to a group (a group is listed alongside the item and I can click through it's link to view the group) however when passing the group as part of a filter to the Item no results are returned -

Group -

```
reader = UploaderBase().open_from_blobstore(Settings().get_group_csv_key())
upNum = 0
groupsToPut = []
for row in reader:
    group = Group(Id=int(row[0]))
    group.Name = row[2]
    groupsToPut.append(group)

db.put(groupsToPut)
```

Item -

```
groupCache = {}
for group in Group.all().fetch(1000):
    groupCache[group.Id] = group
logging.info("Cached %d group entries locally" % len(groupCache))

items = []
reader = UploaderBase().open_from_blobstore(Settings().get_items_csv_key())
upNum = 0
for row in reader:
    logging.debug("Adding row %d" % upNum)
    item = Item(Id=int(row[0]))

    if not row[1] is None and  row[1] != "":
        item.Group = groupCache[int(row[1])]

    item.Name = row[2]
    items.append(item)

db.put(items)
```

Comment: Looks like there may be an issue with what you are actually saving within the Item.Group field.  Can you post your entity creation code?

Comment: Your Python code doesn't work because you are attempting to filter based on the 'Id' property, but passing in the id from the key (18), not the value of the 'Id' property (34). You should probably delete the Id property entirely and just use datastore generated IDs or key names.

Comment: It seems likely that your GQL statement isn't succeeding simply because there are no matching records. Have you tried retrieving a record that you think should match, and checking its Group property? One other possibility is that you had the property set as `indexed=False` when you loaded the data.

Comment: @Nick Johnson - RE: ID's The 34 is the Id from the Item, the item returns a group with an Id of 18. The problem is that the group doesn't return any items when passed to the GQL. Sadly I can't remove the Id column (though I can rename it if it became necessary) because it is used to interface with another system. On the index side that could be a good call. Is there any way that I can force GAE to rebuild an index?

Comment: @Wolfwyrd Why not just use the foreign system's id as the key name (turn it into a string first)? _Did_ you insert the rows with indexed=False? If so, you need to fetch and put every entity to have them indexed correctly.

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks to @Nick-Johnson I traced the issue to the Group index being turned on AFTER the items had been imported. I did a fetch/put on all group items and this resolved the issue. Can you add your comment as an answer please Nick and i'll flag it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that when you inserted the data, the reference property was set as `indexed=False`. Changes to a model only affect entities written after the model was changed, so rows inserted while indexing was disabled for that column will not have index rows.